# DRF local variable 'msg_data' referenced before assignment

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

This is my `serializers.py`

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
img_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_img_count')
post_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_post_count')
msg_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_msg_count')

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('id', 'username', 'img_count', 'post_count', 'msg_count')

def get_img_count(self, obj):
    try:
        img_data = ImgSerializer(Img.objects.filter(author=obj.id), many=True)
    except img_data.DoesNotExist:
        return 0
    return img_data

def get_post_count(self, obj):
    try:
        post_data = PostSerializer(Post.objects.filter(author=obj.id), many=True)
    except post_data.DoesNotExist:
        return 0
    return post_data

def get_msg_count(self, obj):
    try:
        msg_data = Smessage(Msg.objects.filter(author=obj.id), many=True)
    except msg_data.DoesNotExist:
        return 0
    return msg_data
```

This is my `views.py`

```
class UserProfile(APIView):
permission_classes = [AllowAny]
def get(self, request):
    query = User.objects.all()
    serializer = UserProfileSerializer(query, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

This is the [Error Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWAwI.png)

I want to get this

{
        "id": 9, 
        "username": "emil@gmail.com", 
        "img_count:3, 
        "post_count":5, 
         "msg_count":50, 
}

also getting error after using img_count.count().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the exceptions to:

```
img_data.DoesNotExist --> Img.DoesNotExist
post_data.DoesNotExist --> Post.DoesNotExist
msg_data.DoesNotExist --> Msg.DoesNotExist
```

Because, instances does not have any exception object, rather the model classes has them. More information can be found in [**`documentation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.DoesNotExist).

### Update

If you just want the count, then you don't need to use such extensive implementation. You can simply try:

```
def get_img_count(self, obj):
    return Img.objects.filter(author=obj.id).count()

def get_post_count(self, obj):
    return Post.objects.filter(author=obj.id).count()

def get_msg_count(self, obj):
    return Msg.objects.filter(author=obj.id).count()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set default value of each variable because in case of error other than DoesNotExist, you will face this error.

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    img_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_img_count')
    post_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_post_count')
    msg_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_msg_count')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'img_count', 'post_count', 'msg_count')

    def get_img_count(self, obj):
        img_data = 0
        try:
            img_data = ImgSerializer(Img.objects.filter(author=obj.id), many=True).data
        except Img.DoesNotExist:
            pass
        return img_data

    def get_post_count(self, obj):
        post_data = 0
        try:
            post_data = PostSerializer(Post.objects.filter(author=obj.id), many=True).data
        except Post.DoesNotExist:
            pass
        return post_data

    def get_msg_count(self, obj):
        msg_data = 0
        try:
            msg_data = Smessage(Msg.objects.filter(author=obj.id), many=True).data
        except Msg.DoesNotExist:
            pass
        return msg_data
```